# TF31002: Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

on my computer I have a problem with connection to TFS 2013 using Visual Studio 2013 and 2015. This problem occurs on only one machine. Other users in the net can work without problems. In the same time I can connect to projects on Visual Studio Online. Problem happened after switching a few times between projects. Nothing was installed or changed either on my computer or on TFS Server. I've got following error: "Technical information (for administrator): The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF".

I've check this article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.tfc.connecttotfs.unabletoconnect)&rd=true

But in section: "You receive this error when you try to connect to an on-premises TFS from your client computer " I didn't found solution. I also reinstalled Visual Studio but it didn't solved my problem.

How to solve this? Is there a way to check some logs or events to find a reason? Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards Pawel

Comment: Could you provide detailed error message you got when try to connect to TFS？

Comment: @Pawel, did you try every steps described in the "You receive this error when you try to connect to an on-premises TFS from your client computer" part in this MSDN article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244143.aspx ?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Fortunately I solved this problem. But there were so many activities to do that, that I can't reproduce my steps to share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

To  narrow down this problem, try the following actions:

1.check whether there is something wrong with  user account

a)  Connect to TFS with the same user  on another machine.

b)  Login in tfs web access in web browser with your account

2.Clear TFS local cache http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/07/06/Clear-the-cache-of-TFS.aspx For TFS 2013 the default path: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache